# Mapbox: Change weight of circle on hover

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I have drawn a circle using L.circle with weight 1px. I want to change the weight to 2px on hover with a smooth animation.

Comment: we can do this using" this.setStyle({weight:2})" but how to do it with animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for changing the "weight" of the L.Circle (which is in fact its SVG shape "stroke-width") on hover, you would simply bind callbacks on `"mouseover"` and `"mouseout"` events:

```js
myCircle.on({
  "mouseover": function () {
    myCircle.setStyle({
      weight: 2
    })
  },
  "mouseout": function () {
    myCircle.setStyle({
      weight: 1
    })
  }
});
```

As for the smooth animation, you would have 2 options:

- CSS3 transition on SVG properties. But IE does not support them unfortunately.
- Fallback to implementing the animation / transition yourself, typically using `setInterval` or `requestAnimationFrame`, and adjusting the weight gradually.

With CSS3 transition on SVG properties:

JavaScript:

```js
var myCircle = L.circle(myLatLng, myRadius, {
  weight: 1,
  className: "test"
})
```

CSS:

```css
.test {
  transition: stroke-width 1s; /* duration with unit */
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/115/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.Can you please tell me, what svg property should I use to add a transition to radius change?

Comment: Unfortunately the L.Circle "radius" is part of the SVG shape itself, it is not reachable as easily through CSS. That would probably be a different question for you to post to get a proper answer.